# Docker configs/secrets are always user/group writable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It seems like whenever I use a secret/config they are always group and user writable, even when I set the mode explicitly non-group writable. Example compose file:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  alpine:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: ["stat", "/foo"]
    secrets:
      - source: foo
        target: /foo
        mode: 400

secrets:
  foo:
    file: foo
```

Permissions from stat:

```
Access: (0620/-rw--w----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

I set it as 400 in the compose file, but in the container it is 620!

This seems a bit odd and is problematic for me as I want to use this for ssh which errors if files such as user/host keys are group writable. The only other option I have is to bake the config into the image, which I would like to avoid if possible.

This is a question I asked on the forums originally, but I thought I might as well post it here too: https://forums.docker.com/t/secrets-configs-always-group-writable/65458

Comment: What is the owner/group (`chown`) and permissions (`chmod`) for the secrets file `foo` on the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a leading 0, otherwise yaml notation will parse the number as a decimal instead of an octal number:

```
mode: 0400
```

Octal 620 is decimal 400.

See the yaml spec: https://yaml.org/type/int.html

Also the examples in the compose documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-2

Comment: OF COURSE. Thanks a lot. I had no idea YAML had special handling of octal numbers, but I should have guessed it was something with oct/dec.